# Permit anyone to use a method in a secured Spring Rest Repository

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm using **Spring Data Rest** and **Spring Security** in a **Spring Boot** project.
I have a security annotation that allow `ADMIN` users to execute all methods : `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")` at the class level.

I want that only one method of this repository (`findByPersonalNumber`), which is used in the Spring security Authentication process (cf `UserDetailsService`), without any security.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Optional<User> findByPersonalNumber(String personalNumber);
}

@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public AuthenticationService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.getByPersonalNumber(username);
        return new CurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

When i try to execute the Authentication process, which use the method `findByPersonalNumber` of the repository, i have this kind of exception :

```
2015-08-13 10:11:02.989 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2015-08-13 10:11:11.193 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=permitAll()) found on specific method: public final java.util.Optional com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.findByPersonalNumber(java.lang.String)
2015-08-13 10:11:11.193 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116; public abstract java.util.Optional xxx.repositories.UserRepository.findByPersonalNumber(java.lang.String)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'permitAll()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2015-08-13 10:11:11.193 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=permitAll()) found on specific method: public abstract java.util.Optional com.dassault_systemes.diy.repositories.UserRepository.findByPersonalNumber(java.lang.String)
2015-08-13 10:11:11.193 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository; public abstract java.util.Optional xxx.repositories.UserRepository.findByPersonalNumber(java.lang.String)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'permitAll()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2015-08-13 10:11:11.193 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract java.util.Optional xxx.repositories.UserRepository.findByPersonalNumber(java.lang.String); target is of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'permitAll()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2015-08-13 10:11:11.194 DEBUG 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
2015-08-13 10:11:11.195 ERROR 1654 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.findByPersonalNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.dassault_systemes.diy.service.UserServiceImpl.getByPersonalNumber(UserServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.dassault_systemes.diy.service.AuthenticationService.loadUserByUsername(AuthenticationService.java:35)
```

I also tried the `@PreAuthorize` annotation with `isAnonymous()` value without better result.

Comment: You have already pre-authorized the whole interface, changing a single methods security does not allow you to bypass it. I'd recommend refactoring to move the method to a more public interface.

Comment: @RobinJonsson I would like to keep all my methods in the same Repository interface. Maybe i can delete the pre-authorize in the whole interface and override all the methods to add the pre-authorize annotation on each one but would like to find a cleaner way.

Comment: Then you'd have to set the whole pre-authorization query on each method. `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') && @currentUserService.canAccessUser(principal, #id)")`

Comment: @herau Hi, did you solve the issue? How do you manage it? I faced the similar issue and I would like to find an optimal solution.

Comment: I didn't find a solution, as far as i remember